VS Code Testing - creating testing profiles to run different options
I am using pytests with python-django in VS Code. I just discovered that there is an option to select a Default Profile in VS Code's Testing tab. Not sure how this was enabled. Are there any documentations to add a profile? I couldnt find anything online.
If I add a new profile, will it allow me to switching between pytests options easily (i.e. --reuse-db).

